# Using symfony with a proxy

Tags: symfony, curl, proxy

I'm tying to install symfony on my computer at work, with standalone [uWamp](http://www.uwamp.com/fr/) as local server.

Since the php command from the doc (`php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"`) didn't work for me ("failed to open a stream"), I had to manually get the installer at `https://symfony.com/installer` to even be able to use the symfony php command.

But even then, when I run `php symfony new my_project`, I get this curl error which I dont know how to outpass :

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 7: Failed to
> connect to get.symfony.com port 443: Timed out
>
> [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 7: Failed to
> connect to get.symfony.com port 443: Timed out

From what I read on SO, I think my problem is that there is a proxy that forbid my connexion.

Here is the list of main SO topics on the subject :

- [TimeOut connection to symfony.com via http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360073/timeout-connection-to-symfony-com-via-http-proxy) : no answer and I don't have any control over the proxy (I dont even have any access to its parameters). I tried downloading composer and have the very same problem.
- [How to handle Fatal error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to xxxx port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617480/how-to-handle-fatal-error-curl-error-7-failed-to-connect-to-xxxx-port-443) : this is try/catch, and I am definitively not going to rewrite symfony
- [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host) : they say I should change my proxy port, but how can I do it before symfony execution ?

Is there any way I can use symfony on this computer ? Else, is there a standalone vanilla version of symfony I could use without it to download anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the problem is. But the solution was ping get.symfony.com from the computer where it works. And the address in /ect/hosts

Comment: and the address in /etc/host WHAT?

Comment: sudo nano /etc/hosts, and append "13.32.145.87 get.symfony.com". Sorry for bad english